# Hindu Symbolism Of Kali Maa Earrings

Tags: symbolism, kali

Kali Maa’s earrings are dead bodies of babies, like this is from Exotic India book excerpt description :

“her ornaments are a garland or necklace of severed human heads, girdle of severed human arms, ear-rings of infants' corpses, bracelets of snakes -”

Link : https://www.exoticindiaart.com/article/goddess_kali/

I’ve read many weird little theories on this. They don’t seem correct.

Could someone clarify, like what is the symbolism of her earrings as dead babies ?

Comment: "from Exotic India book excerpt description" <- you might want to give reference link to that.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Thx, I edited and put in the link. The description of her earrings as dead babies is in tons of places online, wherever her symbolism is explained. Not sure what it means, have read many peculiar theories over past several months.

Comment: It is not dead babies, that would be silly, in fact kali will remove the “earrings” during battle.  Her ears are the aum sound from either the beginning or end of voidness

Comment: I love the symbolism of Kali Maa & no idea if it’s an oft repeated error or what but her earrings are described as infant corpses or dead babies in many many places. I’m just not exactly sure what it means, and the theories I’ve read didn’t seem quite right. If I can find more info from any reputable sources I’ll link them in comments here 

Comment: Actually, there is a story that i have read somewhere about a form of Maa Kāli. Once two children ate the bhoga given to Maa Kāli and in anger she ate them alive. But when the mother could not find her children anywhere even after searching them every where. She understood what had happened and prayed to mother Kāli to give her children back. So, Mata gave her children back, who came out from both her ears respectively. I forgot the name of the form. You can find it in internet.

Comment: @Savdy Thx friend, I will def look that up. Reminds me of sort of parallel stories from the Manasa Devi & Behula legends, w/ Manasa Devi taking life of the sons of MahaDev-bhakt Chand Saudagar, then later returning his sons alive after he prayed to her. (I am obsessed w/ the ManasaDevi & Behula story, I love so much ! All the powerful Devi stories, they are so so wonderful 

Comment: Yes, they are well as you know, maa Manosha is mostly worshpped in bengal and another interesting thing is that i think in bengāli version of Shiva Purāna Lakhindar was the reincarnation of Anirudha the grandson of Sri Krishna and Behula was of Ushā the daughter of King Bānā. Plus, in BVP, it's said that Aniruddha is the incarnation of Lord Brahmā and Ushā is of Mata Saraswati respectively. So, Behula-Lakhindar were Lord Brahmā snd Maa Saraswati respectively. N bdw, u r most welcome. ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbology of Ma Kali is described by Swami Chetananda here:

https://kalimandir.org/is-kali-terrible/

The 2 babies as her earrings suggest that the Ma's devotees are childlike.

Comment: Thx Pradip ! I’m still looking online to see if there is any other symbolism to the earrings, not coming up w/ anything so far. I try a few more times.

Comment: Thx PG, gonna accept this, it’s the closest to interpretations I’m finding of child-like devotees, meaning to be guileless, to have no evil in the character, so telling a good person types quality 